# Styling Data Grids in GWT - Multiple Grids in one project

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I am attempting to have multiple data grids in a single project.  They have some different behavior and therefore different styling.  The first grid is a fully custom grid, building the rows with an AbstractCellTableBuilder with a fully custom CSS file (using the DataGrid.Resources override).

The issue I am having is that my second grid's custom CSS is being applied to my first grid.  I don't see any coding overlap.  It just seems like the CSS classes are being anonymized the same, so they show up on the elements both grids.

Any thoughts?

Please let me know if there is anything I can provide to clarify the situation.

UPDATE:

ReportSelectorGrid.css has every class required by the DataGrid.Style defined.  All of them are empty.

```
    private SelectorDataGridResources gridResource = GWT.create(SelectorDataGridResources.class);
    public interface SelectorDataGridResources extends DataGrid.Resources {
        @Source({ "ReportSelectorGrid.css" })
        DataGrid.Style dataGridStyle();
    };
```

And then this is in my UiFactory method:

```
    DataGrid<ReportSelectorItem> grid = new DataGrid<ReportSelectorItem>(-1, gridResource, KEY_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: Can you provide your DataGrid.Resources custom implementation and also  code where you instantiate your DataGrid?

Comment: Done.  Thanks for looking at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare a `DataGrid.Style` sub-interface or they'll all share the same obfuscated class names. See also: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6144

Comment: Oh man, I've been searching for days.  I can't believe I didn't come across this posting.  Thank you!!

Comment: And I'm sure it's been asked several times here too, though probably never about `DataGrid` specifically…